# Failed to build gem native extension when installing OpenSSL

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rubygems

So I am following this tutorial: https://meta.discourse.org/t/beginners-guide-to-install-discourse-on-macos-for-development/15772 but when I use `bundle install` it gives me this error:

```
An error occurred while installing openssl (2.2.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install openssl -v '2.2.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

along with

```
Installing openssl 2.2.0 with native extensions
Installing cppjieba_rb 0.3.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
```

but why do I get this?

Running `gem install openssl -v '2.2.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` gives me...

```
Building native...
ERROR:  Error installing openssl:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/openssl-2.2.0/ext/openssl
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210225-70291-10x2bpm.rb extconf.rb
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-openssl-dir
    --with-openssl-include
    --without-openssl-include=${openssl-dir}/include
    --with-openssl-lib
    --without-openssl-lib=${openssl-dir}/lib
    --with-kerberos-dir
    --without-kerberos-dir
    --with-kerberos-include
    --without-kerberos-include=${kerberos-dir}/include
    --with-kerberos-lib
    --without-kerberos-lib=${kerberos-dir}/lib
    --with-debug
    --without-debug
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-openssl-config
    --without-openssl-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
extconf.rb:99:in `<main>': OpenSSL library could not be found. You might want to use --with-openssl-dir=<dir> option to specify the prefix where OpenSSL is installed. (RuntimeError)

To see why this extension failed to compile,

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/openssl-2.2.0/mkmf.log

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/openssl-2.2.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/openssl-2.2.0/gem_make.out
```

Again, why does this happen? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

`openssl` gem is basically a set of wrappers around `openssl` library. And bundler cannot find the library in your system during *Building native extensions* step. Thus the gem fails to install.

This is weird as the script you linked explicitly installs `openssl` long before bundling gems

> ```
> log_info "Upgrading and linking OpenSSL ..."
>   brew install openssl
>   brew link openssl --force
> ```

Check the script's output for errors (and check if it has reached this step at all). You will probably find the reason for missing openssl library there (or simply try to install openssl manually more using the commands above).

After you install the `openssl` library check its version using command

```
openssl version -a
```

If you have a custom openssl library installation it might help to follow the advice from the error message and install openssl gem manually while specifying the path to openssl library

Comment: Do you know where is the path to the openSSL lib?

Comment: Wait so I keep getting "Invalid option --with-openssl-dir"

Comment: Ok I bypassed that openSSL error but now I have ```An error occurred while installing nokogumbo (2.0.4), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogumbo -v '2.0.4' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.```

Comment: And running any rake commands give me:

```Could not find openssl-2.2.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.```